# codeigniter show webpage even in offline mode using cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, dictionary, caching

I am using Cache in Codeigniter
I can successfully saved cache files on cache folder.

But how can I show it to the user when internet is gone?

Im using ouput->cache (n)
I also have google maps that need to be saved the cache map.

Comment: Cache files are stored on your server so your server does not have to repeat processes. If a user has no internet connection it is impossible for them to access anything from your server. The user will have to save a local copy of the page(s) for offline use.

Comment: There are couple of things you should know to achieve that.  If you wants your app to run in offline mode you can use service workers and manifest. In manifest you can  store js files locally. For Db syncing you can use PouchDb.

Answer (score 0):

Cache is stored on server, to reduce the processing time. If user do not have internet he will not be able to see your page.